# JQuery datepicker doesn't work in multi jsp page

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jsp, jakarta-ee, datepicker

I'm using datepicker in my jsp pages but the problem that the datepicker work just in the page that initialise the datepicker and not in the other pages.

i initialise (just one time) datepicker like that : `$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );` to use French calender, in the js file of the main page (i include the other page in the main, to get the same header and footer for all pages)

I like to know why doesn't work, i think the fist page that call datepicker lock it and we can just use it in this page.

my code looks like :
firstJsp.jsp :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.checkbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.ibutton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-ui-datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/firstJsp.js"></script>
...
<input type="text" id="RegDate" class="datepicker"/>
...
```

firstJsp.js and secondJsp.jsp (same code)

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() { 
   ...
   $(".datepicker").datepicker();
   //$(".datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
   ...
  });
```

mainJsp.js use ajax to get pages and include it into a `<div id="subPage"></div>` in the mainJsp.jsp page

```js
  ...
  success : function(data){
   $('#subPage').html(data);
   }
  ...
```

any suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: _work just in the page that initialize the datepicker_ You need to __initialize__ in other pages also

Comment: Because  on each your page  JavaScript bootstrapping  again and lose state of previous page (your initialization)

Comment: `$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );` this is your whole code ?

Comment: @Satpal i initilize the datepicker in all pages, but always work just in one page

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr i'm Ok with you, i call the init function in `$(document).ready(..)`

Comment: can we see your code ?

Comment: If it does not work on another pages that mean that you  didn't initialize  datepicker on this page or  you miss  some library for them ( like jQuery).

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr it work just in the first page that i invoque, when i call 'firstJsp.jsp' work and dosn't work in 'firstJsp.jsp' if i call 'secondJsp.jsp' firstly

Comment: @SupunPraneeth yes, i modified my post

Comment: so `firstJsp.jsp` is a subpage that load through the ajax ?

Comment: yes, `firstJsp.jsp` and `secondJsp.jsp` are subpages that i load it through ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i load the jqyery libery more then one time when i visit sub pages, and that's why the datepicker work just in the first load of sub page and dosn't work in the other pages.

i hope that my solution can help